# De-duplicating a pandas data frame and taking the newest record

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame with duplicates and update dates. Starting Date:
[image: Sample Data]

What I am looking for is a way to remove duplicates and take the newest record. I know about drop_duplicates() but that only drops the rows that are 100% identical. So the desired output would look like:
[image]

I have tried things like this:

```
grouped = df.groupby(['First Name', 'Middle Name','Last Name','Job Title','Active','Contractor'])
new_data = grouped['Update Date'].agg(np.max).to_frame().reset_index()
```

But there has to be a better way of doing this than grouping by every column then taking the max of the updated date. 
What if I wanted to group by certain columns, and take the max update date. BUT also take the other columns that didn't get grouped by.

For instance grouping by First, middle and Last name and still taking the entire record of the newest record.

Input:[image]

Desired output. [image]

Thanks!

Comment: It might be best to have a key that uniquely identifies each person. I'm assuming here that first, middle and last uniquely identify the person. What happens if there are two people with the same name or someone has a name change? You need to think about these things first.

Comment: Either way I would need to find a way to group and take the newest record

Comment: For future reference you will have faster responses if you supply a code version of your dataframe (`df = ....`) so that we can copy-paste it. The pictures look pretty but don't help to get a dataframe like yours to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My comment notwithstanding, you can order the entire dataframe first and then take the first row of every group.

```
df = df.sort_values('Update Date', ascending=False)
df.groupby(['First Name', 'Middle Name','Last Name']).first().reset_index()
```

Answer (score 3):

`drop_duplicates` takes a `subset` argument:

```
ident_fields = ['First Name', 'Middle Name','Last Name']
df = (df.sort_values('Update Date')
      .drop_duplicates(subset=ident_fields, keep='last'))
```